# Fatal error encountered during command execution Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, load-data-infile

I am developing a small application which aims to transfer a lot of data into a MySql table.
To do this I use an load data infile but it returns this error to me : Fatal error encountered during command execution.

I have however already used this same code before and it worked correctly but there I really do not see where the error can come from.
There is code to write data in txt file :

```
    public static void WriteDataTable(DataTable sourceTable, TextWriter writer, bool includeHeaders)
    {
        if (includeHeaders)
        {
            IEnumerable<String> headerValues = sourceTable.Columns
                .OfType<DataColumn>()
                .Select(column => QuoteValue(column.ColumnName));

            writer.WriteLine(String.Join("µ", headerValues));
        }

        IEnumerable<String> items = null;

        int i = 1;
        foreach (DataRow row in sourceTable.Rows)
        {
            items = row.ItemArray.Select(o => QuoteValue(o?.ToString().Replace(',', '.').Replace("\r\n", " ") ?? String.Empty));
            writer.WriteLine(String.Join("µ", items));
            if (i == 3) break;
            i++;
        }

        writer.Flush();
    }

    private static string QuoteValue(string value)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(String.Concat("\"", value.Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\""), @"\\", @"\\");
    }
```

There is the code to call the load data infile :

```
        string tempFileCsv = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\UserData\tempUsers.txt";

        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempFileCsv))
            {
                WriteCsv.WriteDataTable(dt, writer, false);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        //Injection via sql
        try
        {
            string query = @"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + tempFileCsv + "' INTO TABLE users FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'µ' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ";
            MySqlCommand commandCreate;

            commandCreate = new MySqlCommand(query, this.mysqlCo);
            commandCreate.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Données chargées avec succès !");
        //System.IO.File.Delete(tempFileCsv);
```

Here is an example of the content of my txt file :

```
"1"µ"SYSTEM"µ"MCP133"µ"PARFILUX"µ"W:\\WINBOOKS\\DATA\\PARFILUX"µ"F"µ""
"2"µ"SYSTEM"µ"MCP133"µ"TEST"µ"W:\\WINBOOKS\\DATA\\TEST"µ"F"µ""
"3"µ"SYSTEM"µ"MCP133"µ"CJARDIN2"µ"W:\\WINBOOKS\\DATA\\CJARDIN2"µ"F"µ""
```

and here is the structure of my mysql table :
[image]

Thank in advance ;)

Content query in debug :
[image]

Comment: Why do you use such strange delimiters ? " Fatal error encountered during command execution" should mean there is a internal exception executing the SQL query. The ```WriteDataTable``` method also seems very complicated, but let's assume it works. Can you debug it to the point where the string ```query``` is assigned and show the content ?

Comment: Will ```string tempFileCsv = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\UserData\tempUsers.txt"``` really generate the right path the file is stored at ?

Comment: Have you validated that the files ends in \r\n and where does the exception occur? Is it on the MySqlException catch?

Comment: I use a special delimiter but it works correctly. the path is correct and the file is well generated I modified my post and added the content of the query

Comment: the error is caused when I try to execute the load Data infile at the level of the line : commandCreate.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 0):

Switch to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) and use the [`MySqlBulkCopy`](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbulkcopytype/) class to load a `DataTable` directly.

```cs
using var connection = new MySqlConnection("...;AllowLoadLocalInfile=True");
await connection.OpenAsync();
var bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(connection);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "users";
await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dt);
```